# Difference between the use of FOR FETCH ONLY in query & ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY in JDBC statement

Tags: db2, query-optimization, database-deadlocks, db2-zos

My application is running 200 select statements per second (like SELECT A, B, C FROM DUMMYSC.DUMMYTB, etc.). 10-15% of the queries fail with the error below:

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033, SQLERRMC=00C9008E;00000304;DSNDB06 .SYSTSTSS.X'000001C5'.X'0C'`

I'm looking to use one of the solutions below, but unable to understand the difference between the two.

**ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY** in
`statement = connection.createStatement (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);`

&
**FOR FETCH ONLY** in `SELECT A, B, C FROM DUMMYSC.DUMMYTB FOR FETCH ONLY`.

Comment: What is the __isolation level__ ?

Comment: default isolation level - CS.

Comment: The error message also gives SQLERRMC=00C9008E, which resolves to a timeout (Reference - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n913.html). I would still like to know the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

`For fetch only`  (aka `For Read only` ) prevents the cursor from being used in a positioned update or positioned delete statement (i.e. `Update ...WHERE CURRENT OF cursor-name`,  or `DELETE...WHERE CURRENT OF cursor-name`).

At jdbc level on the client, the ResultSet concurrency option determines whether the java code can update the result-set contents or not. If you do not need the cursor to be scrollable then don't use TYPE_SCROLL_*, instead use TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY as that should improve concurrency. `CONCUR_READ_ONLY` and `FOR FETCH ONLY` work together.

Sometimes it's best to ensure a plan-specific isolation level by using a `WITH CS` or `WITH UR` clause on the query, instead of depending on the package isolation or some default that you don't control.

For Db2-on-Z/OS, If your application can cope with incomplete results, i.e. if that makes business sense, then you can use `SKIP LOCKED DATA` in your query. For Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, other registry settings and special register settings are available to get similar  behaviour.

There's also the `USE AND KEEP...LOCKS`  syntax in the isolation clause of the query, which influences the duration of locks.

Cannot tell from your question whether the result-set is read-only by nature (for example, if the query is from a read only view ), or how your java code runs the query (via a prepared statement or not?) , these influence outcomes.

A DBA will be able to show you exactly what locks your transaction is taking, for a specific combination of settings for the jdbc cursor/Resultset and  query syntax .

Comment: The java code uses a PreparedStatement to query for read-only view, this runs on tables outside a transaction

Comment: after going through the master task for the subsystem, I found that the underlying dataset was removed, that why the query timed out and gave me an error code that primarily spoke of deadlock, and misleads me.

Answer (score 0):

The information you posted is not enough to decide what caused the timeout on the table space access. It could be other SQLs holding the lock or some of these 200 SQLs attempting update, or others.

But if you know for sure that you don't need to update the data in your SQL and you don't worry about dirty read, then you should specify "FOR READ ONLY WITH UR" in your query. This not only avoids any potential timeout caused by other SQLs but also lowers the resource overhead and improves the system performance.

Comment: Isn't SQLERRMC=00C9008E, as per IBM documentation refer to timeout ?

Comment: @NoCodeDefFound it is, but my comment was: no enough info to decide "what caused the timeout", timeout can be caused by many different reasons. To use FOR READ ONLY WITH UR for the queries that you know for sure you don't need to update or don't care about the dirty read would help you avoid unnecessary hold.